# О семантике слова "ремесло"

Tags: семантика

Можно ли сказать, что варение сыра — ремесло?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нет. Это скорее фермерство(если предполагается последующая реализация сыра) . Вот здесь http://samsebeyurist.by/predprinimatelstvo/remeslennichestvo прописаны виды деятельности, относящиеся к ремесленничеству. Производство продуктов питания даже в домашних условиях там не предусматривается. Это ответ с юридической точки зрения, так же следует разобраться с этимологией слова "ремесло". Ремесло́. Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. -slo, ср. весло, масло, свясло и т. д.) от той же основы, что латышск. remesis «плотник», того же корня (с перегласовкой о/е), что рубить, лит. ramtýti «рубить» и т. д. Ремесло буквально — «плотничество».
Происхождение слова ремесло в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Шанского Н. М.
Как видим родословная "ремесла" тянется к плотничеству. На мой взгляд, лишь с развитием цивилизации этот термин обрёл более широкое значение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно.

ремесло
Требующая специальных навыков работа по **изготовлению** каких-л. изделий ручным, кустарным способом.

Так вот *сыр* — кулинарное изделие.